# Finding a class avg within a nested loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, while-loop

I am working a small practice program that will allow you to input the 3 test scores in for as many students as you'd like and at the end I would like it to calculate the average between all the students. I am able to enter all the students name and scores and it will give me back their average but when you enter "*" it only calculates the last students average and I was trying to figure out how to make it calculate all the students average from their test scores

```
def GetPosInt():     
        nameone = str

        while nameone != "*":

            nameone =(input("Please enter a student name or '*' to finish: "))

            if nameone != "*":
                scoreone = int(input("Please enter a score for " + nameone +": "))

                if scoreone < 0:
                    print("positive integers please!")
                    break

                else:
                    scoretwo = float(input("Please enter another score for "+nameone+": "))
                    scorethree = float(input("Please enter another score for "+nameone+": "))

                testscores = scoreone + scoretwo + scorethree
                avg = testscores / 3
                print("The average score for",nameone,"is ",avg)   
                classtotal = avg

            if nameone == "*":
                classavg = classtotal / 3
                print("The class average is: ",classavg)

# main
def main():
    GetPosInt()

main()
```

Comment: I solved it shortly after i posted it so I should've deleted it actually

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. I just wanted to make sure you remembered you'd posted that question. :) As an asker, you aren't obligated to mark answers.

Comment: Also, the solution for this program is a list.

Comment: How would you make it into a list to store the values from the students test average

Answer (score 0, accepted):

COLDSPEED sent you a solution for your question while I was working on it. If you want to see a different solution. It's here... You can put conditions for the scores.

```
def GetPosInt():
    numberOfStudents = 0.0
    classtotal = 0.0
    classavg = 0.0
    while(True):
        nam = (raw_input("Please enter a student name or '*' to finish "))
        if(nam == '*'):
            print("The average of the class is " + str(classavg))
            break
        numberOfStudents += 1.0
        scoreone = float(input("Please enter the first score for " + str(nam) + ": "))
        scoretwo = float(input("Please enter the second score for " + str(nam) + ": "))
        scorethree = float(input("Please enter the third score for " + str(nam) + ": "))
        testscores = scoreone + scoretwo + scorethree
        avg = testscores / 3.0
        print("The average score for " + str(nam) + " is " + str(avg))
        classtotal += avg
        classavg = classtotal / numberOfStudents

def main():
    GetPosInt()
main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simplified version of your code that uses lists to store data for multiple students and then displays these details at the end, and also calculates the class average (comments inlined).

```
def GetPosInt():     
    names = [] # declare the lists you'll use to store data later on
    avgs = []

    while True:
        name = ...

        if name != "*":
            score1 = ...
            score2 = ...
            score3 = ...

            avg = (score1 + score2 + score3) / 3 # calculate the student average

            # append student details in the list
            names.append(name)  
            avgs.append(avg) 

        else:
            break

    for name, avg in zip(names, avgs): # print student-wise average
        print(name, avg)

    class_avg = sum(avg) / len(avg) # class average
```

Comment: How do you see it when I tried to run it I am immediately hit with an error in my code I am almost finished I just need to find out how to store the values from the output coming from 'avg'

Comment: @drewyazzie The `...` is for you to fill up.

Comment: It is stored in a `list` data structure. Please find more here: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists

Comment: drew: I'm sure cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ knows about `list`s. You just need to replace the `...` in this answer with something like the `int(input("Please enter a score for " + name +": "))` similar to what you have in your question.

Comment: @martineau Thank you. The whole point behind the `...` was not to clutter the code with superfluous details. The hope and expectation is that OP can catch on. I wish it weren't the case that everything has to be spelled out so explicitly.

Comment: cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ:  Speaking of superfluous details, you can replace the `while name != "*":` with `while True:` since you check it again at the beginning of the loop. That way you wouldn't have to initialize it to `None` before entering the loop.

Comment: @martineau Good idea... hopefully doesn't confuse OP too much. :)

Comment: Hopefully...and maybe it'll teach them a useful technique in the process. Also, when I have an `if` statement like that where one of the clauses is much shorter than the other, I often reverse the condition and put the shorter one first because I think it's clearer / more readable (especially when using `while True:` which appears to be an infinite loop).